# In R studio, in place of mode and count appearance i have Class: character

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

my problem is that i dont see the counts like in the examples of my studies
Dataset:
[image]

when i do summary i got

[image]

inplace of example of the lesson - they have:

[image]

i am doing exactly the same query, but i dont have the results like in example?
what should i do to get the counts in summery?

Kind regards, Ilya

Comment: Do you want to change your character strings to factors? `and$PersistentieType <-as.factor(and$PersistentieType)`

Comment: wow now i get the same result, what exactly as.factor did? i googled but the explanation is to abstract..

Comment: The lesson is probably outdated. R changed the default import settings for characters in 4.0. Now values are imported as characters rather automatically converted to factors as before.

Comment: Conceptually, factors are variables in R which take on a limited number of different values; such variables are often referred to as categorical variables.

Comment: I guess so, the course is of the year 2019